# What rails route do I need here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I am using code that is similar to a password reset, but I am using it to 'cancel' a 'registration'. In this case a link with a token is being mailed to the user, and they click on that link which takes them to something like...

```
3000/cancel_registration/3Z9XWXExzZ3BzrpooI5flA/edit
```

...where I have...

```
#app/views/cancel_registration/edit.html.erb
<td><%= link_to 'Yes. Cancel my Registration', cancel_registration_path(@registration) %></td>
```

...in my controller I have...

```
#app/controllers/cancel_registration_controller.rb
 def edit
    @registration = Registration.find_by_registration_cancellation_token!(params[:id])
  end

  def cancel
  puts "made it to cancel"
  end
```

...right now here is what I have in my controller...

```
 get 'cancel_registration', to: 'cancel_registration#new', as: 'cancel_registration'
 post 'cancel_registration', to: 'cancel_registration#cancel', as: 'cancel_registration'
```

The get works fine, but not sure how to the the user to the cancel action from my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the http verb to the link:

```
link_to 'Yes. Cancel my Registration', cancel_registration_path(@registration), method: :post
```

Comment: Booya! Chika Chika wah! You nailed it markets...points coming your way.